# Eclipse doesn't seem to recognize java

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-juno

I have installed Eclipse as well as java.
But my Eclipse does seems to be recognizing java installation.

I am using Eclipse Juno and java jre7

Comment: You need to give a lot more information than that. How is Eclipse not recognizing Java?

Comment: Check your path variables and make sure Eclipse finds an existing Java Version. Make sure your projects associate with to a jdk. I can't give and more advice without knowing more

Comment: Please check your Eclipse project facet settings and check whether you have pointed to correct java version. Also you need to add jre system library in eclipse project build path.

Comment: Hint: first of all, start with state of the art versions of eclipse. There is really not much sense in using Juno ... in 2016. That's like n-4 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have install JDK version of Java.
Set the JAVA_HOME variable.
If Eclipse still doesn't recognize, manually select the java to be used in the project settings

Answer (score 2):

You can provide the Java path manually to eclipse so that it recognises Java.

Go to Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs.

Click on Add, select standard VM, Click Next.

It will open a window and allow you to select JRE path

Once this is done, your problem should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Just installing the  JRE is not enough, that is just the run time environment,  for Eclipse as IDE and for you as developer a *development kit* is required so you need the **jdk** in order to use Eclipse, no matter what version...